# JQuery scrolling share icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to implement my own social share icons. I've got everything working the way I'd like but I've run into a slight issue. I want to make the icons scroll alongside the content with the user so I use `jQuery` by doing this:

**HTML**

```
<div id='blogpost'>
  <div id='social'>
        <ul class='fa-ul'>
           <li class='fb'><a href="#"><i class='fa fa-facebook'></i></a></li>
           <li class='twitter'><a href="#"><i class='fa fa-twitter'></i></a></li>
           <li class='google'><a href="#"><i class='fa fa-google'></i></a></li>
           <li class='linkedin'><a href="#"><i class='fa fa-linkedin'></i></a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
   <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
   <p>My text...</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var stickyTop = $('#social').offset().top; //Get top of the social div

    $(window).scroll(function(){ //Scroll event - executed each time user scrolls
       var windowTop  = $(window).scrollTop(); 

       if(stickyTop < windowTop){
           console.log('sticky');
           $('#social').addClass('stick');
       }else{
           console.log('normal');
           $('#social').removeClass('stick');
       }

    });

});
```

The `#social` div has following `CSS` which displays it slightly to the left of the blog post. This is perfect.

```
div#social {
    position: absolute;
    left: -80px;
    top: 45px;
}
```

When I scroll I then add the `.stick` class to the `#social` and the position is updated from absolute to fixed. This is causing inconsistency on mobile devices. When I resize the screen sometimes the icons appear behind the post rather than just slightly to the left. Is there a way I can update my CSS to ensure the icons are always just slightly to the left ??

You can see my JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/c7jwtcfr/4/

Thank you.

Comment: if this is displaying correctly, you have a big monitor :) You might want to do media queries with `calc()`.

Comment: If you moved the .stick below the #social you wouldn't need to specify !important on all of the styles. When I edit your codepen to set .stick { left: 20px } it seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, changing the left value in .stick is sufficient:

```
.stick{
    left: 18px !important;
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 55px !important;
}
```